# how to stretch an image in GTK+?

Tags: c++, user-interface, gtk

I'm using the following code to set the background Image but as size of image is small I want to stretch the size to fit the screen or if the image is larger than screen in that case too I need the same.

Im using Gtk+3.2

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
GtkWidget *window;
GtkWidget *layout;
GtkWidget *image;
GtkWidget *button;

gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 290, 200);
gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);

layout = gtk_layout_new(NULL, NULL);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (window), layout);
gtk_widget_show(layout);

image = gtk_image_new_from_file("/home/my_background_image.jpg");
gtk_layout_put(GTK_LAYOUT(layout), image, 0, 0);

button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Button");
gtk_layout_put(GTK_LAYOUT(layout), button, 150, 50);
gtk_widget_set_size_request(button, 80, 35);

g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy",
G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

gtk_widget_show_all(window);

gtk_main();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've worked in DirectFB and there are always 4 coordinates to put an image, here are just 2.

Comment: Did you try making the `GtkLayout` expand to fill available space? A screenshot would help somewhat.

Comment: see this for screenshot http://postimg.org/image/rw5halr6b/  . And I don't know how to expand `GtkLayout` to full available space.

Comment: Weird, I tried inlining the image but SO says "format not supported" for both the JPEG preview and the PNG actual image. Fail.

Comment: You'll probably want to use CSS and GtkStyleContext for this instead of a GtkLayout. Override the `background-image` on your GtkWindow.

Comment: Thank you!! but can you please tell me some tutorial or guide to use this, Im new to GTK

Comment: On your GtkWindow, call `gtk_widget_get_style_context()`. Create a new [GtkCssProvider](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCssProvider.html), load it with some CSS to do what you want, and call `gtk_style_context_add_provider()` to add the provider to the style context. More information on GTK+ CSS is in the linked GtkCssProvider documentation, under Description.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you really need layout for setting background image. 
You can overload "draw" signal and in handler you can paint background image.
The following code will work for you.

```
gboolean GtkDrawing::window_draw_cb (GtkWidget * widget, cairo_t * cr, cairo_surface_t* m_bgImage)
{
    gint root_width,root_height;

        cairo_set_source_surface (cr,m_bgImage, 0, 0);

        gtk_window_get_size (GTK_WINDOW(widget), &root_width, &root_height);
        cairo_rectangle (cr, 0, 0,root_width, root_height);
        cairo_fill (cr);

        //Enable Below code to draw child widget after background rendering
        //gtk_widget_draw (childwidget, cr);
        //cairo_fill (cr);


    return TRUE;
}

cairo_surface_t* m_bgImage=cairo_image_surface_create_from_png("/home/my_background_image.png");
g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), "draw", G_CALLBACK(GtkDrawing::window_draw_cb), m_bgImage);
```

In the above handler function, to stretch the image you can modify cairo_rectangle parameters.